# Power Query: Reformatting DDMM to MMDD based on existing date

Tags: date, powerquery

I'm trying to transform my data in Power Query so that they can be analysed by month. All data should be dated the 1st of the month, but a formatting change in the past has made some entries come up as "2/01/2022" instead of "1/02/2022" for February.

[image: Starting table to ending pivot table]

I normally would be able to do this in Excel but I would like to transform the data from the live database (SMSS) instead of using an export. So far, I can identify the rows that need changing but I keep getting errors when I try to use my IFs...

[image: What I've managed so far...]

The step I'm stuck at:

```
#"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Custom", each if [Text Before Delimiter] <> "1" then Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"Date", type date}}, "en-US") else [Date])
```

If anyone knows how to use IF nicely in Power Query please let me know how the syntax here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about testing the day, and if it is not =1, swap month and day

```
#"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Custom", each if Date.Day([Date])=1 then [Date] else #date(Date.Year([Date]),Date.Day([Date]),Date.Month([Date])))
```